# ¿ Cómo evitar que se salgan las imágenes del primer `div`?

Tags: html, css, imagen, div

Hola encontré una galería de imágenes en codepen, creada por Olaman y estoy intentando agregar a mi proyecto.
La galería muestra un panel con unas listas verticales por las que al pasar el ratón, se despliegan las imágenes, apartando el resto de listas a los lados.
Bien, como dije tienen 5 imágenes, y yo quiero añadir 2 o 3 imágenes más. Pero como veréis en el ejemplo, al añadirlas se salen las imágenes por la parte de abajo del `div`.
Con cinco funciona de maravilla, según pasamos el ratón por cada lista, se despliegan las imágenes una por una en el mismo `div`, apartando al resto sin problema.
Por mas que le dado vueltas, no soy capaz de conseguir, probé a reducir el tamaño de las listas iniciales, sin éxito. 
No se que mas hacer. 
¿ Como podría meter más imágenes sin que se rompiera el efecto y permanecieran todas en el `div`?
Muestro el ejemplo.
Gracias.

**EDITO:**
Para poner la [la fuente donde](https://codepen.io/oloman/pen/Gynoq)  lo encontré, a petición de un compañero.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  background: #ccc;
}
ul.acordeon * {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}

ul.acordeon {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  background: #04850A;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333;
}

ul.acordeon li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline; zoom: 1; /* IE7 */
  width: 10%; 
  height:0;
  padding-bottom: 40%; /* Ratio aspecto imagen = (height*X)/width */
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 8px #999;
}
/* Títulos pestañas */
ul.acordeon li h4 {
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 10% 120%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 10% 120%;
  transform-origin: 10% 120%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
/* Contenido inicialmente oculto */
ul.acordeon li a, ul.acordeon li img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline; zoom: 1; /* IE7 */
  width: 0;
  padding:0;
  background: #333;
}
/* Hover: Desplegamos elemento aumentando su ancho */
ul.acordeon li:hover {
  width: 60%; /* 100 - 10*(nºelem-1) // X=60 para ratio imagen */ 
  background: #333;
}
/* Hover: Hacemos que el título recupere la horizontal y le ponemos un fondo */
ul.acordeon li:hover h4 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: #04850A;
  color: #eee;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}
/* Hover: Expandimos el contenido */
ul.acordeon li:hover a, ul.acordeon li:hover a img {
  width: 100%; 
}
/* Ajustes para resoluciones pequeñas */
@media(max-width:600px) {
  ul.acordeon li h4 {
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
}

/* VARIACIONES PARA CONSEGUIR QUE EL MENU OCUPE INICIALMENTE TODO EL ANCHO 
ul.acordeon li {
  width: 20%;
}
ul.acordeon:hover li {
  width: 10%;
}
ul.acordeon li:hover {
  width: 60%;
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS responsive accordion gallery/menu</title>
  <link href="css/style-desbroces.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="acordeon">
  <li>
    <h4>Yecla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-na8syCqA5QM/U2Y0MkeZeFI/AAAAAAAAPyA/5C7WeCVpcyE/s900/yecla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Ricote</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-0VLtdXRmROw/U2Y0MBkDjKI/AAAAAAAAPx8/2WHDkLKpo3g/s900/ricote.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Bullas</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-dx4GDtQCuCY/U2Y0LT8IlRI/AAAAAAAAPxo/4XW_d21QrMk/s900/bullas.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Jumilla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8vVOgYUvpRA/U2Y0LTWXwFI/AAAAAAAAPxs/HPnmp59MYtk/s900/jumilla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Jumilla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8vVOgYUvpRA/U2Y0LTWXwFI/AAAAAAAAPxs/HPnmp59MYtk/s900/jumilla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Abanilla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yyHs3e39Tsg/U2Y0LHHoRmI/AAAAAAAAPxk/TnqknfWjR0s/s900/abanilla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Abanilla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yyHs3e39Tsg/U2Y0LHHoRmI/AAAAAAAAPxk/TnqknfWjR0s/s900/abanilla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disminuye el 60% en 20% (10% por cada imagen) en el selector:

```
ul.acordeon li {
  padding-bottom: 40%;
}
```

Para hacer que la imagen en las pestañas ocupe todo el ancho, como antes, debemos modificar unas cosas.

1. Aislar el selector de la imagen aparte. Este: `ul.acordeon li img`
2. En este selector nuevo, declaramos el ancho y el alto proporcional de la imagen.
3. Añadimos la clase que hará la magia: `object-fit: cover`
4. Para que de el efecto que aparece, pondremos por defecto su `opacity` en `0`.

   - Si lo que deseas es que también aparezca desde la esquina inferior
     derecha, debes agregar `transform-origin: 100% 100%;` y `transform: 
     scale(0)`. Ejemplo:

```
ul.acordeon li img{
  width: 400px; /**/
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;  
  opacity: 0;
}
```

5. Busca además el selector de multiples clases que controlar el efecto de **"hover"**: `ul.acordeon li:hover a, ul.acordeon li:hover a img` y corta el de la imagen: `ul.acordeon li:hover a img`.
6. Pega el selector, copiado anteriormente, aparte y añadele un `opacity: 1;`

   - Para la animación que aparezca desde la esquina inferior derecha. Agrega en este mismo selector: `transform: scale(1) ;`

Te recomiendo además, añadir un `overflow: hidden;` al contenedor de las pestañas: `ul.acordeon li`

Ejemplo:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  background: #ccc;
}
ul.acordeon * {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}

ul.acordeon {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  background: #04850A;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333;
}

ul.acordeon li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline; zoom: 1; /* IE7 */
  width: 10%; 
  height:0;
  padding-bottom: 40%; /* Ratio aspecto imagen = (height*X)/width */
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 8px #999;
}
/* Títulos pestañas */
ul.acordeon li h4 {
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 120%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
/* Contenido inicialmente oculto */
ul.acordeon li a,
ul.acordeon li img{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline; zoom: 1; /* IE7 */
  width: 0;
  padding:0;
  background: #333;
}

ul.acordeon li img{
  width: 100vmax;
  height: 75vmax;
  object-fit: cover;  
  opacity: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: scale(0);
}
/* Hover: Desplegamos elemento aumentando su ancho */
ul.acordeon:hover li:hover {
  width: 40%; /* 100 - 10*(nºelem-1) // X=60 para ratio imagen */ 
  width: 70%;
  background: #333;
}
/* Hover: Hacemos que el título recupere la horizontal y le ponemos un fondo */
ul.acordeon li:hover h4 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: #04850A;
  color: #eee;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}
ul.acordeon:hover li{
  width: 5%; 
}
/* Hover: Expandimos el contenido */
ul.acordeon li:hover a{
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
}

ul.acordeon li:hover a img{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

/* Ajustes para resoluciones pequeñas */
@media(max-width:600px) {
  ul.acordeon li h4 {
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
}

/* VARIACIONES PARA CONSEGUIR QUE EL MENU OCUPE INICIALMENTE TODO EL ANCHO 
ul.acordeon li {
  width: 20%;
}
ul.acordeon:hover li {
  width: 10%;
}
ul.acordeon li:hover {
  width: 60%;
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS responsive accordion gallery/menu</title>
  <link href="css/style-desbroces.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="acordeon">
  <li>
    <h4>Yecla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-na8syCqA5QM/U2Y0MkeZeFI/AAAAAAAAPyA/5C7WeCVpcyE/s900/yecla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Ricote</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-0VLtdXRmROw/U2Y0MBkDjKI/AAAAAAAAPx8/2WHDkLKpo3g/s900/ricote.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Bullas</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-dx4GDtQCuCY/U2Y0LT8IlRI/AAAAAAAAPxo/4XW_d21QrMk/s900/bullas.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Jumilla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8vVOgYUvpRA/U2Y0LTWXwFI/AAAAAAAAPxs/HPnmp59MYtk/s900/jumilla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Jumilla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8vVOgYUvpRA/U2Y0LTWXwFI/AAAAAAAAPxs/HPnmp59MYtk/s900/jumilla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Abanilla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yyHs3e39Tsg/U2Y0LHHoRmI/AAAAAAAAPxk/TnqknfWjR0s/s900/abanilla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Abanilla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yyHs3e39Tsg/U2Y0LHHoRmI/AAAAAAAAPxk/TnqknfWjR0s/s900/abanilla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

### Alternativa con nuevas herramientas

Además, te propongo esta estructura, que realiza lo mismo pero con flexbox y variables css, para un mayor control sobre el acordeón.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  background: #b2b2b2;
}
ul.acordeon * {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.acordeon {
  width: var(--ancho);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 var(--space);
  background: Darkcyan;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.my_settings{
  /*Espacio entre las pestañas y el acordeon*/
  --space: 0;
  /*Ancho del acordeon*/
  --ancho: 90%; /*Tamaño que desees*/
  /*Numero de pestañas */
  --n: 8;
  /*Ancho de cada pestaña*/
  --x: calc( 100% / var(--n) );
  /*Altura del acordeon*/
  --y: 80vh; /*puedes colocarlo en pixeles, em o lo que quieras*/
  /*Opcional: Ancho de pestañas no seleccionadas al momento de agrandar*/
  --x1: calc(var(--x) / 2); /*entre mayor el número, más pequeñas se harán las otras pestañas*/
  /*Opcional: Ancho de pestaña ampliada*/
  --x2: calc( var(--x) * (var(--n) - 1) ); 
}

.acordeon li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: center;
  *display: inline; zoom: 1; /* IE7 */
  width: var(--x); 
  height: var(--y);
  background: #d2d2d2;
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 8px #999;
}

.acordeon:hover li{
  width: var(--x1);
}

.acordeon:hover li:hover{
  width: var(--x2); /*o puedes reemplazarlo por 100%*/
  width: 100%;
}

.acordeon h4{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 1em;
  min-width: 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: 
    translateY(-1em)
    translateX(.25em)
    rotateZ(90deg);
}

.acordeon li:hover h4{
  padding-left: .5em;
  color: white;
  min-width: 100%;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  background: rgba(100,255,100,.8);
}

.acordeon li img{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 100% 120%;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.acordeon li:hover img{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS responsive accordion gallery/menu</title>
  <link href="css/style-desbroces.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="acordeon my_settings">
  <li>
    <h4>Yecla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-na8syCqA5QM/U2Y0MkeZeFI/AAAAAAAAPyA/5C7WeCVpcyE/s900/yecla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Ricote</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-0VLtdXRmROw/U2Y0MBkDjKI/AAAAAAAAPx8/2WHDkLKpo3g/s900/ricote.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Bullas</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-dx4GDtQCuCY/U2Y0LT8IlRI/AAAAAAAAPxo/4XW_d21QrMk/s900/bullas.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Jumilla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8vVOgYUvpRA/U2Y0LTWXwFI/AAAAAAAAPxs/HPnmp59MYtk/s900/jumilla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Jumilla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8vVOgYUvpRA/U2Y0LTWXwFI/AAAAAAAAPxs/HPnmp59MYtk/s900/jumilla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Abanilla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yyHs3e39Tsg/U2Y0LHHoRmI/AAAAAAAAPxk/TnqknfWjR0s/s900/abanilla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Abanilla</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yyHs3e39Tsg/U2Y0LHHoRmI/AAAAAAAAPxk/TnqknfWjR0s/s900/abanilla.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Ricote</h4>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-0VLtdXRmROw/U2Y0MBkDjKI/AAAAAAAAPx8/2WHDkLKpo3g/s900/ricote.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El problema es que se reduce la imagen mucho, y de la parte de arriba se reduce casi a la mitad ¿ NO hay manera de evitarlo @Edgar Gutiérrez ? Gracias.

Comment: La idea es que fuera amplía la imagen, si no se pudiera, la dejaría como el original, con cinco. Edite la pregunta para poner donde la cogi, que me dijo un compañero.

Comment: **ATENCIÓN:** En caso de que quieras dar soporte a Internet Explorer (que espero que no), la segunda opción no será válida @MiguelEspeso. Lo puedes ver [aquí](https://caniuse.com/#search=var). Cual ha sido mi sorpresa al ver que ya soportan las variables el resto de navegadores...

Comment: Ya las hice todo el alto del `div` modificando lo siguiente `.acordeon li img{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 100% 120%;
  transform: scale(0);
}` Gracias de nuevo @Edgar Gutiérrez. Ahora tratare de que se hagan mas grandes al mostrarse, ya con lo que me has mostrado creo que lo conseguiré.

Comment: A ver @EdgarGutiérrez , me lo has dejado muy explicado en tus comentarios, pero soy incapaz de que al pasar el ratón se hagan el doble de grandes que ahora, o tres veces mas. y me modificado varias de las medidas. Que debo modificar?. No se si debería formular otra pregunta con la cuestión. Gracias.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero **De hecho** estas confundiendo las **variable font** con las **css variables**, pero es un error común, ya que en realidad en la documentación oficial están como "[custom properties](https://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20properties)", lo digo por el link que colocaste, porque lo otro si esta bien dicho jejeje, lo importante es darle soporte a los navegadores nuevos, internet explorer es algo del pasado y si quieres darle soporte hay formas, pero lo aconsejable es no usar nuevas propiedades.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso es decir quieres que sean más grandes que como están ahora que ya cubren el 100% de todo el contenedor? Sí entendí bien, cambia la escala, es decir recuerda que usamos: `transform:` y ajustamos la escala en 1 para que volviera a su tamaño normal, pero si quieres que escale al doble de tamaño, usa `scale(2)` incluso puedes usar decimales: `scale(1.2)` o `scale(2.5)`, etc

Comment: Nada, con esa escala no consigo que aumenten de tamaño. Lo suyo seria un tamaño como el de mi ejemplo, que la imagen ocupe casi 3/4 de la pantalla, algo mas de la mitad. Seguire intentandolo. Gracias @EdgarGutiérrez .

Comment: @MiguelEspeso Entonces no quieres agrandar la imagen, que es lo que te dije, sino los `li` para que sean el doble de grandes que ahora. En realidad es que tienes que usar matemáticas para entender cómo agrandar más esa imagen que necesitas, es por eso que te sugiero usar variables, para que los cálculos se hagan solos. Yo añadi ya el cambio al 1er ejemplo de mi respuesta, simplemente cambie el ancho de los otros `li` de 10% a 5% usando: `ul.acordeon:hover li` y al **hover** del `li` cambia el ancho de 40% a `width: 70%`, valor que sale del calculo: (100% - (5% x 6)).

Comment: Grave, si te parece difícil no es un buen ejemplo, ya que la idea es que agregues la clase de **my_settings** al `acordeon`, agregues el css que propongo (que es menos del que tienes actualmente) y cuando lo quieras usar, solo debas modificar las variables de la clase **my_settings** y ya.

Comment: Por cierto en el primer ejemplo con los cambios que le hice, tampoco te sirvio? Porque la idea no es que no lo logres o yo lo apunte a la respuesta, si es necesario, creamos un pen en [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/pen) y trabajamos en tu código hasta que lo logres.

Comment: @EdgarGutiérrez No, realmente no me he confundido, sabía de que estaba hablando :P, lo único que había que hacer un poco de scroll para poder verlo en caniuse (de hecho creo que han salido 12 resultados cuando he puesto var), porque sale el segundo resultado. Ahora si que he visto que se llaman diferente y por eso no me aparecía antes en primer lugar :/

Comment: Edgar y @MiguelEspeso cuando podais, borrad los comentarios obsoletos para dejar limpia la publicación. Un saludo ^^